# Problem with host-only in Virtual Box

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox

I have virtualbox software in my computer and I have windows 7 in host.
my virtual has windows server 2008 and Sql server 2008 I have client SQL version in windows 7(host computer) but as you know virtualbox works in host-only network. I need Connection host to guest but I can not see virtual computer(win2008) from host (win7).
Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox let's you choose [several modes for the VM virtual NIC](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes). The mode that I seem to have the most success with is "bridged networking". Try changing this setting on you VM NIC and seeing if it works. If it still doesn't work, try deleting the virtual NIC, and then re-creating it.

If that doesn't fix it, try creating a new VM, and making the current virtual hard disk the drive for the new VM. Sometimes the VM configuration file becomes corrupted in some way (not the hard disk, just the configuration file), and creating a new VM fixes the problem.